# Can't set screen resolution and frequency at start-up

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, ubuntu-gnome, nvidia-settings

I've been manually setting my resolution/frequency for a while and decided it's finally time that I stop doing that, as it isn't saved after restart.
Specifically, while my session does start in native resolution, it always default to 60Hz instead of 144Hz.

I would like to avoid setting the frequency after the start of the session.

After trying different things for a few hours, I come here hoping for help.

**What works:**

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144
```

alternatively, the nvidia-settings gui allows to change the frequency

**What I tried:**

editing the /etc/gdm/Init/Default file with

```
PATH="/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/X11R6/bin:$PATH"
OLD_IFS=$IFS

xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144
xset m 1/1 100

if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
  /sbin/initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm
fi
...
```

(disregard xset, used for mouse settings)

That would have been way too easy, this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried to use the "save to X configuration file" feature of nvidia-settings, but I still end up at 1920*1080@60Hz after restart (nvidia-settings ran with sudo)

So I ran:

```
cvt 1920 1080 144
```

which output

```
# 1920x1080 143.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 169.35 kHz; pclk: 452.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
```

and edited again `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` file with:

```
PATH="/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/X11R6/bin:$PATH"
OLD_IFS=$IFS

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_144.00" 452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1920x1080_144.00 
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080_144.00

xset m 1/1 100

if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
  /sbin/initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm
fi
...
```

same result.

Here is the content of my `xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 352.21  (buildd@lgw01-37)  Thu Jul 23 11:50:49 UTC 2015

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 352.63  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-11)  Sat Nov  7 22:00:19 PST 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VG248"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 150.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 770"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_144 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I discovered the "metamodes" "1920x1080_144 +0+0" line
and tried editing `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` file with

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080_144
```

and

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode "1920x1080_144.00 +0+0"
```

without better result.

I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10.

I use Nvidia proprietary drivers (352.63) for my GTX 770  (GK104) graphic card.

Comment: You could try to add the `xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144` to the "Application Autostart" in the "Session and Startup" of your user profile.

Comment: adding `/usr/bin/xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144` does work, but this happens after session start I believe :(

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english. I've same problem. Restart at 60hz on Auto. under Mint 18 or Ubuntu 16.

The only way have found at this time, is to edit xorg.conf, and activate

```
Option         "Xinerama" "1"
```

... but is not a good way for me, i've discover at least one game won't start ( Talos principle ): say RandR extension not present.